# New AD Users always has 'Never' checked for account expires

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I am using a PS script to create a new AD user, but even if I have the expiry date in the script, the new user always gets the 'Never' checked.

The script:

```
New-ADUser -name '<NAME>' -AccountExpirationDate (get-date).addDays(30) -UserPrincipalName '<USERPRINCIPALNAME>' -GivenName '<FIRSTNAME>' -Surname '<SURNAME>' -DisplayName '<DISPLAYNAME>' -Manager '<MANAGER>' -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText '<PASSWORD>' -Force) -enabled $true -PasswordNeverExpires $false -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Path '<PATH>' -Server '<SERVER>'
```

[image: The User Panel shows that the Account never expires]

The above script creates an user in the AD but under 'Account expires' , 'Never' is checked, although I see a +30 day date in the 'End Of' field ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. Is there something else in the script that modifies the user?

Comment: The "+30 day date" on the screenshot is not a value saved with the user. It is always the date 30 days in the future. Any user account that does not expire shows the date 30 days in the future (greyed-out) in ADUC on the "Account" tab. This is a default when you select "End of" for "Account expires". Try to change ´addDays(30)´ to some other value and it will still show +30 in ADUC. I think it must be some policy somewhere that sets new accounts to never expire.